# React Native Unhandled Exception [object Object]

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

My app React native app runs fine but once in a while when I leave it and open again it crashes giving me the below error:

```html
Date/Time:       2022-10-06T17:17:16.999Z
Launch Time:     2022-10-06T14:24:34Z
OS Version:      iPadOS 15.7 (19H12)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGABRT
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x1b7791b38
Crashed Thread:  14

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: [object Object]', reason: 'Unhandled JS Exception: [object Object]'

React Exception Stack:
RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: [object Object]: Unhandled JS Exception: [object Object]
0   construct@(null):(null)
1   construct@(null):(null)
2   p@47:359 construct.js:19
3   s@45:362 wrapNativeSuper.js:26
4   construct@(null):(null)
5   <unknown>@44:473 ExceptionsManager.js:16
6   v@44:661 ExceptionsManager.js:16
7   handleException@44:1912 ExceptionsManager.js:135
8   <unknown>@43:184 setUpErrorHandling.js:24
9   reportFatalError@4:191 error-guard.js:49
10  value@62:2612 MessageQueue.js:370
11  value@62:730 MessageQueue.js:113
12  value@(null):(null)

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018091e288 0x0000000180885000 + 627336
1   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x0000000199652744 0x000000019963c000 + 91972
2   Safeair                              0x000000010036c790 RCTFatal (RCTAssert.m:147)
3   Safeair                              0x00000001003ef2f0 -[RCTExceptionsManager reportFatal:stack:exceptionId:extraDataAsJSON:] (RCTExceptionsManager.mm:77)
4   Safeair                              0x00000001003efc30 -[RCTExceptionsManager reportException:] (RCTExceptionsManager.mm:147)
5   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001808a6b24 0x0000000180885000 + 138020
6   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001808c4610 0x0000000180885000 + 259600
7   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001808fb5fc 0x0000000180885000 + 484860
8   Safeair                              0x000000010039fefc -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] (RCTModuleMethod.mm:584)
9   Safeair                              0x00000001003a253c facebook::react::invokeInner(RCTBridge*, RCTModuleData*, unsigned int, folly::dynamic const&, int, (anonymous namespace)::SchedulingContext) (RCTNativeModule.mm:183)
10  Safeair                              0x00000001003a2170 ___ZN8facebook5react15RCTNativeModule6invokeEjON5folly7dynamicEi_block_invoke (RCTNativeModule.mm:104)
11  libdispatch.dylib                    0x0000000180583e6c 0x0000000180582000 + 7788
12  libdispatch.dylib                    0x0000000180585a30 0x0000000180582000 + 14896
13  libdispatch.dylib                    0x000000018058d124 0x0000000180582000 + 45348
14  libdispatch.dylib                    0x000000018058dc80 0x0000000180582000 + 48256
15  libdispatch.dylib                    0x0000000180598500 0x0000000180582000 + 91392
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f09110bc 0x00000001f0910000 + 4284
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f0910e5c 0x00000001f0910000 + 3676

Thread 14 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001b7791b38 0x1b778a000 + 31544
1   libsystem_c.dylib                    0x000000018ba32524 0x18ba12000 + 132388
2   Safeair                              0x00000001005f5d0c uncaught_exception_handler.cold.1 + 24
3   Safeair                              0x00000001005d661c uncaught_exception_handler (PLCrashReporter.m:371)
4   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018099f570 0x180885000 + 1156464
5   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x0000000199658c5c 0x19963c000 + 117852
6   Safeair                              0x00000001005ca89c MSACCrashesUncaughtCXXTerminateHandler() + 708
7   libc++abi.dylib                      0x000000019975cf18 0x19974c000 + 69400
8   libc++abi.dylib                      0x000000019975ceb4 0x19974c000 + 69300
9   libdispatch.dylib                    0x0000000180585a44 0x180582000 + 14916
10  libdispatch.dylib                    0x000000018058d124 0x180582000 + 45348
11  libdispatch.dylib                    0x000000018058dc80 0x180582000 + 48256
12  libdispatch.dylib                    0x0000000180598500 0x180582000 + 91392
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f09110bc 0x1f0910000 + 4284
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f0910e5c 0x1f0910000 + 3676

Thread 0:
0   libz.1.dylib                         0x00000001f0436510 0x1f0431000 + 21776
1   ImageIO                              0x00000001823bc0e4 0x182388000 + 213220
2   ImageIO                              0x00000001823b7514 0x182388000 + 193812
3   ImageIO                              0x00000001823e2f80 0x182388000 + 372608
4   ImageIO                              0x00000001823a7304 0x182388000 + 127748
5   ImageIO                              0x00000001823a80cc 0x182388000 + 131276
6   ImageIO                              0x00000001823eeebc 0x182388000 + 421564
7   ImageIO                              0x00000001823a2410 0x182388000 + 107536
8   ImageIO                              0x000000018239ddf0 0x182388000 + 89584
9   ImageIO                              0x00000001823a5f70 0x182388000 + 122736
10  QuartzCore                           0x0000000184662464 0x1845c9000 + 627812
11  QuartzCore                           0x00000001846b394c 0x1845c9000 + 960844
12  QuartzCore                           0x00000001845fae14 0x1845c9000 + 204308
13  QuartzCore                           0x00000001846105c0 0x1845c9000 + 292288
14  QuartzCore                           0x00000001846194a8 0x1845c9000 + 328872
15  UIKitCore                            0x0000000183058308 0x182d05000 + 3486472
16  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001808f75a4 0x180885000 + 468388
17  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001808f8500 0x180885000 + 472320
18  CoreFoundation                       0x0000000180890070 0x180885000 + 45168
19  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001808a3bc8 0x180885000 + 125896
20  GraphicsServices                     0x000000019ca13374 0x19ca12000 + 4980
21  UIKitCore                            0x0000000183219b58 0x182d05000 + 5327704
22  UIKitCore                            0x0000000182f9b098 0x182d05000 + 2711704
23  Safeair                              0x000000010028c22c main (main.m:8)
24  ???                                  0x00000001009a9da4 0x0 + 0

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001b778b4a0 0x1b778a000 + 5280
1   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018088bd30 0x180885000 + 27952
2   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001808901bc 0x180885000 + 45500
3   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001808a3bc8 0x180885000 + 125896
4   Foundation                           0x0000000182096444 0x18207d000 + 103492
5   Foundation                           0x00000001820d7e0c 0x18207d000 + 372236
6   UIKitCore                            0x0000000183193cc4 0x182d05000 + 4779204
7   Foundation                           0x00000001820e641c 0x18207d000 + 431132
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f09119ac 0x1f0910000 + 6572
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f0910e68 0x1f0910000 + 3688

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001b778b4a0 0x1b778a000 + 5280
1   Safeair                              0x00000001005e5920 exception_server_thread (PLCrashMachExceptionServer.m:674)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f09119ac 0x1f0910000 + 6572
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f0910e68 0x1f0910000 + 3688

Thread 3:
0   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018ca76924 0x18baea000 + 16304420
1   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018bf898d8 0x18baea000 + 4847832
2   Safeair                              0x0000000100449150 facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createValue(OpaqueJSValue const*) const (JSCRuntime.cpp:1381)
3   Safeair                              0x000000010044a45c facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::getProperty(facebook::jsi::Object const&, facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&) (JSCRuntime.cpp:875)
4   Safeair                              0x000000010044abb4 facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::size(facebook::jsi::Array const&) (JSCRuntime.cpp:1033)
5   Safeair                              0x0000000100452620 facebook::jsi::dynamicFromValue(facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&) (jsi.h:767)
6   Safeair                              0x00000001004557cc facebook::react::JSIExecutor::callNativeModules(facebook::jsi::Value const&, bool) (JSIExecutor.cpp:420)
7   Safeair                              0x0000000100454ec4 facebook::react::JSIExecutor::callFunction(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, folly::dynamic const&) (JSIExecutor.cpp:270)
8   Safeair                              0x00000001004473f8 std::__1::__function::__func<facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::runOnExecutorQueue(std::__1::function<void (facebook::react::JSExecutor*)>)::$_8, std::__1::allocator<facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::runOnExecutorQueue(std::__1::function<void (facebook::react::JSExecutor*)>)::$_8>, void ()>::operator()() (function.h:505)
9   Safeair                              0x000000010038ad34 facebook::react::tryAndReturnError(std::__1::function<void ()> const&) (function.h:505)
10  Safeair                              0x0000000100397df0 facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::tryFunc(std::__1::function<void ()> const&) (RCTMessageThread.mm:69)
11  Safeair                              0x0000000100397ba4 ___ZN8facebook5react16RCTMessageThread8runAsyncENSt3__18functionIFvvEEE_block_invoke (function.h:505)
12  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001808f75a4 0x180885000 + 468388
13  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001808f8500 0x180885000 + 472320
14  CoreFoundation                       0x0000000180890070 0x180885000 + 45168
15  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001808a3bc8 0x180885000 + 125896
16  Safeair                              0x000000010038030c +[RCTCxxBridge runRunLoop] (RCTCxxBridge.mm:335)
17  Foundation                           0x00000001820e641c 0x18207d000 + 431132
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f09119ac 0x1f0910000 + 6572
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f0910e68 0x1f0910000 + 3688

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001b778bf24 0x1b778a000 + 7972
1   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018bbd44c8 0x18baea000 + 959688
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f09119ac 0x1f0910000 + 6572
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f0910e68 0x1f0910000 + 3688

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001b778c164 0x1b778a000 + 8548
1   WebRTC                               0x0000000100dc0450 0x100cac000 + 1131600
2   WebRTC                               0x0000000100dc2bb4 0x100cac000 + 1141684
3   WebRTC                               0x0000000100dc2124 0x100cac000 + 1138980
4   WebRTC                               0x0000000100dc3660 0x100cac000 + 1144416
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f09119ac 0x1f0910000 + 6572
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f0910e68 0x1f0910000 + 3688

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001b778bf24 0x1b778a000 + 7972
1   WebRTC                               0x0000000100dbaff4 0x100cac000 + 1110004
2   WebRTC                               0x0000000100dbaed0 0x100cac000 + 1109712
3   WebRTC                               0x0000000100dbda28 0x100cac000 + 1120808
4   WebRTC                               0x0000000100dc2bb4 0x100cac000 + 1141684
5   WebRTC                               0x0000000100dc2124 0x100cac000 + 1138980
6   WebRTC                               0x0000000100dc3660 0x100cac000 + 1144416
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f09119ac 0x1f0910000 + 6572
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f0910e68 0x1f0910000 + 3688

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001b778bf24 0x1b778a000 + 7972
1   WebRTC                               0x0000000100dbaff4 0x100cac000 + 1110004
2   WebRTC                               0x0000000100dbaed0 0x100cac000 + 1109712
3   WebRTC                               0x0000000100dbda28 0x100cac000 + 1120808
4   WebRTC                               0x0000000100dc2bb4 0x100cac000 + 1141684
5   WebRTC                               0x0000000100dc2124 0x100cac000 + 1138980
6   WebRTC                               0x0000000100dc3660 0x100cac000 + 1144416
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f09119ac 0x1f0910000 + 6572
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f0910e68 0x1f0910000 + 3688

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001b778b4a0 0x1b778a000 + 5280
1   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018088bd30 0x180885000 + 27952
2   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001808901bc 0x180885000 + 45500
3   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001808a3bc8 0x180885000 + 125896
4   AudioSession                         0x0000000189ebaf04 0x189eb4000 + 28420
5   AudioSession                         0x0000000189ec48f0 0x189eb4000 + 67824
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f09119ac 0x1f0910000 + 6572
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f0910e68 0x1f0910000 + 3688

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001b778b4a0 0x1b778a000 + 5280
1   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018088bd30 0x180885000 + 27952
2   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001808901bc 0x180885000 + 45500
3   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001808a3bc8 0x180885000 + 125896
4   CFNetwork                            0x00000001813201dc 0x1810a8000 + 2589148
5   Foundation                           0x00000001820e641c 0x18207d000 + 431132
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f09119ac 0x1f0910000 + 6572
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f0910e68 0x1f0910000 + 3688

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001b778b4a0 0x1b778a000 + 5280
1   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018088bd30 0x180885000 + 27952
2   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001808901bc 0x180885000 + 45500
3   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001808a3bc8 0x180885000 + 125896
4   Foundation                           0x0000000182096444 0x18207d000 + 103492
5   Safeair                              0x00000001003bc3e0 -[_RCTSRRunLoopThread main] (RCTSRWebSocket.m:1624)
6   Foundation                           0x00000001820e641c 0x18207d000 + 431132
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f09119ac 0x1f0910000 + 6572
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f0910e68 0x1f0910000 + 3688

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001b778c164 0x1b778a000 + 8548
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f09119ac 0x1f0910000 + 6572
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f0910e68 0x1f0910000 + 3688

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001b778ba74 0x1b778a000 + 6772
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f0910e5c 0x1f0910000 + 3676

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001b778bf24 0x1b778a000 + 7972
1   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018bb32fa0 0x18baea000 + 298912
2   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018baf7f98 0x18baea000 + 57240
3   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018baf8420 0x18baea000 + 58400
4   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018bb54144 0x18baea000 + 434500
5   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018bb56450 0x18baea000 + 443472
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f09119ac 0x1f0910000 + 6572
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f0910e68 0x1f0910000 + 3688

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001b778ba74 0x1b778a000 + 6772
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f0910e5c 0x1f0910000 + 3676

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001b778ba74 0x1b778a000 + 6772
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f0910e5c 0x1f0910000 + 3676

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001b778ba74 0x1b778a000 + 6772
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f0910e5c 0x1f0910000 + 3676

Thread 18:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001b778bf24 0x1b778a000 + 7972
1   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018bb32fa0 0x18baea000 + 298912
2   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018baf7f98 0x18baea000 + 57240
3   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018baf8420 0x18baea000 + 58400
4   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018bb54144 0x18baea000 + 434500
5   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018bb56450 0x18baea000 + 443472
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f09119ac 0x1f0910000 + 6572
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f0910e68 0x1f0910000 + 3688

Thread 19:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001b778bf24 0x1b778a000 + 7972
1   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018bb32fa0 0x18baea000 + 298912
2   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018baf7f98 0x18baea000 + 57240
3   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018baf8420 0x18baea000 + 58400
4   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018bb54144 0x18baea000 + 434500
5   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018bb56450 0x18baea000 + 443472
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f09119ac 0x1f0910000 + 6572
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f0910e68 0x1f0910000 + 3688

Thread 20:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001b778bf24 0x1b778a000 + 7972
1   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018bb32fa0 0x18baea000 + 298912
2   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018baf7f98 0x18baea000 + 57240
3   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018baf8420 0x18baea000 + 58400
4   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018bb54144 0x18baea000 + 434500
5   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018bb56450 0x18baea000 + 443472
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f09119ac 0x1f0910000 + 6572
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f0910e68 0x1f0910000 + 3688

Thread 21:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001b778bf24 0x1b778a000 + 7972
1   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018bb32fa0 0x18baea000 + 298912
2   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018baf7f98 0x18baea000 + 57240
3   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018baf8420 0x18baea000 + 58400
4   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018bb54144 0x18baea000 + 434500
5   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018bb56450 0x18baea000 + 443472
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f09119ac 0x1f0910000 + 6572
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f0910e68 0x1f0910000 + 3688

Thread 22:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001b778bf24 0x1b778a000 + 7972
1   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018bb32fa0 0x18baea000 + 298912
2   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018baf7f98 0x18baea000 + 57240
3   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018baf8420 0x18baea000 + 58400
4   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018bb54144 0x18baea000 + 434500
5   JavaScriptCore                       0x000000018bb56450 0x18baea000 + 443472
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f09119ac 0x1f0910000 + 6572
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001f0910e68 0x1f0910000 + 3688

Thread 14 crashed with arm64 Thread State:
   x21: 0x00000001700ef0e0     x2: 0x0000000000000000    x16: 0x0000000000000148     x3: 0x0000000000000000
   x22: 0x000000011b0bac80     x4: 0x0000000000000010    x17: 0x00000001700ef000   cpsr: 0x0000000040000000
    x5: 0x0000000000000020    x23: 0x00000001daa501b8     x6: 0x0000000000000000    x18: 0x0000000000000000
   x10: 0x04000001d9a74ea1     lr: 0x00000001f09173bc     x7: 0x0000000000013200    x24: 0x0000000000000012
   x11: 0x05000001d9a74ea1     x8: 0xf2b7d399f01d207e    x19: 0x0000000000000006    x25: 0x00000001caede1c0
    x9: 0xf2b7d3988013d07e    x12: 0x000000000000003d     fp: 0x00000001700ee2e0    x26: 0x00000001cb35e2c0
   x13: 0x000000011b83cfc0     pc: 0x00000001b7791b38    x27: 0x0000000180c3f4b3    x14: 0x0000000000000004
   x20: 0x000000000000a80b     x0: 0x0000000000000000     sp: 0x00000001700ee2c0    x28: 0x00000001d72ed9f8
   x15: 0x00000001d9a7fb10     x1: 0x0000000000000000

Binary Images:
0x0000000100284000 -        0x00000001006e3fff +Safeair arm64  <4d604577acb3369396b7738a0a27bfaa> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3E836E7D-8AC8-4911-8F6C-554AD30AC29A/Safeair.app/Safeair
0x0000000100b38000 -        0x0000000100c43fff +HMSSDK arm64  <0088cf12b72c3914be1344c05a3f3996> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3E836E7D-8AC8-4911-8F6C-554AD30AC29A/Safeair.app/Frameworks/HMSSDK.framework/HMSSDK
0x0000000100cac000 -        0x000000010137bfff +WebRTC arm64  <d2a8407854983b788b29246ebc1fca64> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3E836E7D-8AC8-4911-8F6C-554AD30AC29A/Safeair.app/Frameworks/WebRTC.framework/WebRTC
0x0000000180582000 -        0x00000001805c7fff  libdispatch.dylib arm64e  <2d55ad2f6aff303d8e82088ada4695b2> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x0000000180885000 -        0x0000000180cdafff  CoreFoundation arm64e  <da3c2e100c3d3fbc9c3ee950eba7020f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x00000001810a8000 -        0x0000000181569fff  CFNetwork arm64e  <b042dec9ecd133f7ab686207fd1f4a8d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x000000018207d000 -        0x0000000182387fff  Foundation arm64e  <5292a0bd260c3983a5be838997d362f7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x0000000182388000 -        0x0000000182731fff  ImageIO arm64e  <d44076c9006933fcbf0c7f8d6e0f0fd8> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x0000000182d05000 -        0x00000001845a2fff  UIKitCore arm64e  <2a0536acdc79368abe353934c48694c1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
0x00000001845c9000 -        0x00000001848dafff  QuartzCore arm64e  <a357983b56b737ad80b0970654013724> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x0000000189eb4000 -        0x0000000189edefff  AudioSession arm64e  <9c17ea54d7c93c59882062350cd4bb61> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AudioSession.framework/AudioSession
0x000000018ba12000 -        0x000000018ba91fff  libsystem_c.dylib arm64e  <07b35aa1e88436b0902755c91bacaa46> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x000000018baea000 -        0x000000018cf6efff  JavaScriptCore arm64e  <22d6a6386d223121b2bb12df30c79397> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x000000019963c000 -        0x0000000199678fff  libobjc.A.dylib arm64e  <e59c2c92a9dd3af096f7c9837d7e0b27> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x000000019974c000 -        0x0000000199763fff  libc++abi.dylib arm64e  <56952b9c633f3f2e96d7b67ba063bbfa> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x000000019ca12000 -        0x000000019ca1afff  GraphicsServices arm64e  <72f2e29c6aae3587adf9614b48586e5a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x00000001b778a000 -        0x00000001b77bffff  libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64e  <6a661aa2f93f30a39649465ad95b65bc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x00000001f0431000 -        0x00000001f0442fff  libz.1.dylib arm64e  <6766f2b8e2083e5986486aa2636be98e> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x00000001f0910000 -        0x00000001f091bfff  libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64e  <38d5598d7dab3247b6549a0225549fcd> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
```

here is my package.json:

```html
{
  "name": "app-xxx",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@100mslive/react-native-hms": "^0.9.7",
    "@aws-amplify/pushnotification": "^4.3.25",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.7",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.3.0",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.10.1",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.2",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^5.2.10",
    "appcenter": "4.4.5",
    "appcenter-analytics": "4.4.5",
    "appcenter-crashes": "4.4.5",
    "aws-amplify": "^4.3.27",
    "aws-amplify-react-native": "^6.0.5",
    "aws-appsync": "^4.1.7",
    "aws-appsync-react": "^4.0.13",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.6",
    "lottie-ios": "^3.2.3",
    "lottie-react-native": "^5.1.3",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-apollo": "^3.1.5",
    "react-native": "0.69.0",
    "react-native-app-auth": "^6.4.3",
    "react-native-autocomplete-input": "github:mrlaessig/react-native-autocomplete-input",
    "react-native-code-push": "^7.0.5",
    "react-native-draggable": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-exception-handler": "^2.10.10",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-image-mapper": "^0.1.11",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.8.4",
    "react-native-image-viewing": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-keychain": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-maps": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.6.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.15.0",
    "react-native-super-grid": "^4.4.2",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.3.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-swipe-gestures": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.8",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.18",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.69.5",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.11",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.70.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

I cannot find the construct.js file which the traces include. I'm not able to figure out which condition causes the exception. Also the traces doesn't include any details about the code I have or the libraries I have used. can someone help?

Comment: Any help would be appreciated, I've been stuck for a long time now.

Comment: I was running into a similar issue and found a solution. Are you using AWS or GraphQL Subscriptions?

Answer (score 1):

I was running into a similar issue and found that it was related to AWS GraphQL Subscriptions.

The two things that helped fix the error were:

1. Updating the subscriptions with an error handler ([AWS - Github Issue #4667 - #issuecomment-592514952](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/4667#issuecomment-592514952))

- Adding the error handling will allow you to log out of what is occurring. In my case, the connection was timing out. **This is what helped stop the Unhandled Exceptions.**

```
const subscription = API.graphql(graphqlOperation(onCreateMember))
    .subscribe({
        error: err => console.log("error caught", err),
        next: data => console.log("sub data", data),
    });
```

2. For others, the error was related to Buffer. ([AWS - Github Issue #4667 - issuecomment-573409406](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/4667#issuecomment-573409406))

- Adding to the index.js

`global.Buffer = global.Buffer || require('buffer').Buffer;`

Comment: I've spent 2 evenings trying to figure out why my app crashes on testflight & android release. Don't know how I found this but thank you!

Comment: @MÖRK Glad to help!